# Why don't colors match between lines when using line chart with blend?

Tags: linechart, looker-studio

I am trying to visualize data coming from few id's.
I have 2 variables which I want to see in 2 different plots.
When filtering by ID number a few plots together the colors in plot 1 doesn't match the color of the same ID's in the other plot, despite them both being filtered by the same controller.

[image: Plots]

Editable [Google Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/54e1bdd9-4f27-42b2-aca5-1371f9fe387e) report

Editable [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ybLYWuww8o_kdkGIX9SOrTLfruGZ8hIaD5HkC9RD9MY/edit?usp=sharing) with data and keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by changing the colour type from the default, series order, in the **Style** tab:

- ***Colour type***: [Dimension values](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9210318)
- ***Manage dimension value colours***: Set as required to change the respective dimension values in all charts at once

Publicly editable [Google Data Studio report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/403af401-7355-46ff-ab1a-1d7a1a63fae4) (embedded [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fAz1mUsgQETTm2lOgkEZoIlY5ODk61ok5JJ0bG6fCM4/edit?usp=sharing) data source) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image: gif]